# Word for people who are against linguistic purism?

Tags: single-word-requests

This may resemble a question now under a close vote, in which the inquirer asked for names of specific people, but this is not the same.

I am looking for a single word for "one who is against linguistic purity," preferably one with a negative connotation.

Example of how it would be used:
"That Josh favors the use of emoji and the obsoletion of the word 'whom.' He is such a(n) ____."

Thanks!

Comment: Should it be literally against purity of language, or is something like 'non-prescriptivist' sufficient? Or do you mean by purity the lack of borrowing from other languages?

Comment: An 'innovator' or a current day 'modernist'.

Comment: So presumably you disagree with "Josh" (interesting choice of example name), and the word you want should be disapproving or pejorative rather than adulatory? [That needs to be made clear]

Comment: Seems like the answer is a "descriptivist" (see http://www.pbs.org/speak/speech/correct/prescriptivism/) but someone with an academic background might want to chime in.

Comment: @Evan - My exact thoughts, although it doesn't carry the "negative connotation" OP wants. Unless you're a prescriptivist anyway, in which case you probably would think it had a negative connotation!

Comment: What in the world does _the obsoletion of the word 'whom'_ mean? Is this a causative construction, where one forbids its use successfully? Are there any more examples of _obsoletion_ besides 'whom'?

Comment: You might overload 'schlemiel' with this meaning. (- or 'schmuck', but that might be TOO pejorative)

Comment: The obsoletion of a word is the making of that word obsolete. I made it up on the spot, but according to M-W, it seems to be a real word.

Comment: @EsperantoSpeaker1 - Be aware that Schlemiel is a loser, while a schmuck is a dick (in both senses).

Comment: Is your idea of a 'linguistic purist' someone who uses the language exactly as 90% of Oxbridge graduates did in 1950? Someone who uses it 75% of the way that 80% of all UK graduates did in 1930? Someone who uses it the way you think 70% of Anglophones did in 1756? The way you prefer?

Comment: If we're into coining, 'The obsoletion of a word is the making of that word obsolete. I made it up on the spot, but according to M-W, it seems to be a real word [though very rare and not with that meaning]' might suggest that 'Scrooble' is a fair candidate for 'one who does not value linguistic purism'.

Comment: Aargh. Got me there. I concede.

Comment: And yes, I do mean somebody who uses language the way I prefer, now that I think on it.

Comment: Is philistine (person who is hostile or indifferent to culture or the arts) too general for you?

Comment: No, it is not! That is just what I sought! Thanks!

Comment: The definition of the word "philistine" really is much more general than the target definition that you've given in your question. Consider editing the question to reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

A "descriptivist." From a [blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/prescriptivism-and-descriptivism/) here a while ago:

> The idea behind descriptive linguistics is that a language is defined
>   by what people do with it.